# Why resistor is used at the output of OPAMP?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, resistors

I'm reading this [note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0350.pdf) and in Figure 1(page 1), there are two resistors R5 and R10 whose use I don't understand. From my understanding, R5 would cause offset due the input bias current and R10 would load the output. What's the purpose of these resistors and how to calculate their values ?
[image]

Comment: I think R5 and R10 play together, and that the given values minimize the offset from the bias current.  But, that's a guess.  I'll watch this and see what more knowledgeable folks have to say.

Comment: *R5 would cause offset due the input bias current* Hmm, the AD8608 has a max input current of 300 pA, times R5 = 270 ohm => 81 nV, how is that significant? R10 is very likely added to make U1B behave in a more stable way, especially when there is some capacitance on the HREF node. Without R10 it is possible that U1B will oscillate or cause ringing under certain conditions.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, yes I noticed that. I mentioned that because that's the only effect I can think of caused by the R5 on the circuit and it is a negative effect. Also 81nV*(Closed loop gain) will be more, but still negligible for my application.

Comment: Those resistors decrease output current and reduce oscillations. The op amp has ±80 mA output capability at 10 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

R10 definitely looks like an out-of-the-loop compensation to mitigate the influence of capacitive load to U1B (to reduce oscillations, as [Indraneel mentionned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420808/why-resistor-is-used-at-the-output-of-opamp#comment1043919_420808) in comments to the question). See [Practical Techniques to Avoid Instability Due to Capacitive Loading](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/techniques-to-avoid-instability-capacitive-loading.html#:~:text=Out-of-the-Loop%20Compensation), scroll down to "Out-of-the-Loop Compensation". Values of up to 50–100 Ohms are typical.

I hesitate to explain R5 in the same way, though. Its value is on the high side for that purpose, but still plausible. But I don't see from which capacitive load it can isolate U1A, except for the U1D's non-inverting input, which should not be a problem anyway.